# Event.target.value is returning value in different format/unexpected format - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular6, angular7, onchange, dom-events

I am generating dynamic dropdown from model in Angular 6. As the index of selected value will be dynamic I am trying to get value in `(change)` event and assigning it to different model. But when I use `event.target.value` I am getting output is below format which is unexpected :

> "1: bd39b9a1-42f2-4db1-9639-958201062e67"

My expected format is just Guid value like below :

> "bd39b9a1-42f2-4db1-9639-958201062e67"

Do anyone know how to retrieve just Guid value from the above output?

I am able to get value using below method :

```
event.target.value.toString().split(' ')[1];
```

but I need some generic way to do so.

My code is below :

```
<select *ngIf="data.reportTypeTemplate.length == 0"
           (change)="onTemplateChange(type.reportTypeId,$event.target.value,$event)"
            class="form-control rounded-0" formControlName="reportType">
            <option value = "">Select Template</option>
            <option *ngFor="let template of type.reportTemplateName" [ngValue]="template.id">
              {{template.name}}
            </option>
</select> 

onTemplateChange(reportTypeId, reportTemplateId,event){
    console.log("reportTypeId :"+ reportTypeId,"reportTemplateId :"+ reportTemplateId,"event :"+ event.target.value, 'onTemplateChange');
    var templatesData = {"reportTypeId" : reportTypeId,"reportTemplateId" : reportTemplateId};
    this.data.reportTypeTemplateAdd.push(templatesData);
    console.log(this.data);
  }
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle where your problem is reproducible?

Comment: @LajosArpad I am not able to create JSFiddle for it. But I can share my model with you if you need it